# How do you put a number to each occurrence in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is an example of what I am looking for. Each time something occurs, it gets the next sequential number.

[image]

Edit: here is my actual table with data.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and partition it by the `name` column.

```
select row_id
    , name
    , row_number() over (partition by name order by row_id) occurrence
from name_table
order by row_id
```

Here are example results:

[image: Example Results]

Comment: I'd really LOVE to see an actual "Partitioned Sequence" feature added to Sql Server. Until then (which is likely never), generating the values like this at query time (or via trigger, which: eww) is the best we can do.

Comment: i tried using this and it didnt work. Im new to sql and im still creating everything, so i used excel to actually show what i was trying to achieve. I just added in my actual table that i just finished. i got this error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Completion time: 2021-06-09T15:09:07.4621713-04:00 this is the line with row_number() and partition on it.

Comment: @austin here is exactly what i tried,                                                                                  select Tag
 ,ORFinishingDT
 ,occurence
 ,row_id
 row_number() over (partition by Tag order by row_id) occurence
 from ORFinishing
 order by row_id

Comment: @austin im doing it in ssms. it was the comma that i was missing. Thank you very much! i have been beating my head against the wall all day to try to figure this out.